# Applescript-able application & Cocoa issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, scripting, applescript, sdef

I will begin by saying that I'm a complete newbie as far as AppleScript goes. So here you are...

**This is what I've done so far :**

- Studied the apple reference for [SimpleScripting](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimpleScripting/Introduction/Intro.html)
- Implemented an IDENTICAL `.sdef` file
- Set a new property `myname`
- Set principal class (in `info.plist`) to `ppApplication` (my main class inheriting from `NSApplication`)
- Set up the accessor to the `myname` property

**My sdef file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dictionary SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/sdef.dtd">
<dictionary xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2003/XInclude">
    <xi:include href="file:///System/Library/ScriptingDefinitions/CocoaStandard.sdef" xpointer="xpointer(/dictionary/suite)"/>
    <suite name="MyApplication Suite" code="PpRm" description="MyApplication Suite">
        <class name="application" code="capp" description="MyApplication&apos;s top-level scripting object." inherits="application">
            <cocoa class="ppApplication"/>
            <property name="myname" code="PEnm" description="The name of the application" type="text" access="r">
                <cocoa key="myname"/>
            </property>
        </class>
    </suite>
</dictionary>
```

**My ppApplication class :**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "ppCore.h"

@interface ppApplication : NSApplication {
    ppCore* core;
}

@property (assign) ppCore* core;

@property (readonly) NSString* myname;

@end
```

---

```
#import "ppApplication.h"

@implementation ppApplication

@synthesize core;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setCore:[[ppCore alloc] init]];
}

/*******************************************************
 *
 * APPLESCRIPT SUPPORT
 *
 *******************************************************/

- (NSString*)myname
{
    return @"DONE";
}

@end
```

---

### Now, here's the issue :

When I'm trying to run the following script (in **AppleScript Editor**)

```
tell application "myApplication"
     myname
end tell
```

I'm getting a `the variable myname is not defined` error.

### However :

***If I go back to Xcode, Build Settings and change the Product Name to - let's say - myApplicationX and recompile, then the above code (changing it to `tell application "myApplicationX"`) DOES WORK.***

So, what am I doing wrong? Is it possible that the AppleScript Editor doesn't "talk" to my active compilation of the application, but to a previous one? How could I deal with this WITHOUT changing my Product Name?

Comment: Please consider rewriting your question to a *much* more concise form that addresses the real issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was NO issue with the above code.

Simply **restarting AppleScript Editor** (after making any serious changes to the application) does the trick.